# Make JBehave stories not being started if @BeforeStories is failed

Tags: java, automated-tests, jbehave

I need to implement JBehave test running with next requirements:

**1. If @BeforeStories method is failed - test stories should not be started**.
For this I use Configuration 
`MostUsefulConfiguration().doSkipScenariosAfterFailure(false)`

**2. If one scenario in story is failed - next scenario should be started**.
For this I use 
`MostUsefulConfiguration().doResetStateBeforeStory(false).doResetStateBeforeScenario(false)`

These settings work independently, but if I use it together - doSkipScenariosAfterFailure(false) discontinue working

**How to implement this requirements at the same time?**

If story file contains GivenStories: **full.story** 
then full.story still run even with `doResetStateBeforeStory(false).doResetStateBeforeScenario(false)`

I need to fix it also.

Test code:

```
@RunWith(JUnitReportingRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTestStory extends JUnitStory {

    @BeforeStories
    public void beforeStories() throws ExecutionException {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return JBehaveTestHelper.configuration(this.getClass(), xref);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class JBehaveTestHelper {

  public static Configuration configuration(Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass, CrossReference xref) {

      return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .doSkipScenariosAfterFailure(false)
            .doResetStateBeforeStory(false)
            .doResetStateBeforeScenario(false)
}
```

Comment: better to ask in JBehave's user mailing list